# ksh string manipulation $#@!?

Tags: shell, string, ftp, ksh

So  I have this spool file having this kind of content.

```
SQL> select file_name from dev_files;

FILE_NAME
------------------------------------------------------------------
file1.txt
file2.doc
file3.pdf
total.xls

4 rows selected.

SQL> spool off
```

I am writing a ksh script to load these files into a ftp server and update a log file. and I am stuck up bigtime. Here is the portion of my poor code after many tries.

```
dump="spoolfile.txt"

while read line;
do

if [[`expr match "$line" 'SQL'` !=3]] && [[`expr match "$line" 'FILE_NAME'` !=9]] && [[`expr match "$line" '---------'` !=9]]
then
    ftp -inv $tgt_server <<EOT
    quote user $uname
    quote password $pword
    mput $src_path/$line
    quit
    EOT

    echo "sent $line" >> sent_files.log
fi
done < $dump
```

how do i ensure that "no rows selected" and say "4 rows selected." are not read? there can be any number instead of 4 corresponding to number of files. In the case of no files the spool file looks like this. the '.' is also missing.

```
SQL> select file_name from dev_files;

no rows selected

SQL> spool off
```

Comment: Do you have control over the SQL*Plus script generating spoolfile.txt? If so, you can filter those lines out beforehand.

Comment: Ya i thought of that. But it seems the output is needed for another log file.

Comment: Well, that would be the easiest and you could add the needed logging afterwards:set heading off
set feedback off
set pagesize 0
set echo off

Comment: These spool files are generated elsewhere, so probably i cant alter them. Is there a better solution? I had mailed the guy who has access to these scripts. But for the worst case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with most of the comments about 'turn off headings' etc in the SQLPlus,

but this is Easy Peasy ;-)

```
while read line;
do
   case ${line} in 
     -------* ) continue ;;
     FILE_NAME ) continue ;;
     SQL[>] ) continue ;;
     *rows\ selected ) continue ;;
   esac 

   # with enough case match targets, you can probably eliminate
   # the if/fi completely. Good luck.
   if [[`expr match "$line" 'SQL'` !=3]] .....
   ftp ...
   fi
done < $dump
```

You'll have to experiment with what values to put in the case statement to clean it up completely.

Also note that for any unusual characters, like '>', it is probably better to include them as a character class `[>]` (again requiring some experimentation on your part)

And finally, note that if you want to include white-space chars in the case match targets, either surround the phrase in dbl-quotes (") or escape each WS char like '\'.

Comment: hhaha.. first off i am not a shell guru, and was actually expecting some kind of regex answer plus its been some time i had logged in stackoverflow.. ;) also searching for 'selected' wont help as it can be a filename

Comment: If you expect a regex answer, you should indicate that in your question or by your tags. But, no need to get defensive, just up-vote some of the answers you have received that helped you. *** In any case ***, Case statements by design use regexs as the match target. Just because I'm not using the full power of regex in this example doesnt mean they can't be. It is easier to understand code when each case is made explicit. I  will extend my answer a little bit to show good faith, and to show you that case statments can use reg exp.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much more simple soltion: Instead of trying to find lines to ignore, mark the lines to process:

```
select concat("JHFDGFSH ",file_name) from dev_files
```

Now all you need to do is to ignore any line that doesn't start with `JHFDGFSH`.

**[EDIT]** If you can't do that: Start reading when you hit a line that's only `----` and stop at the first empty line. That should work unless Oracle starts to page.

And open an issue for upstream to tell them that their interface is brittle and that it **will break eventually.**

If that's OK, it's not your problem and not your fault when it breaks and production is down for a couple of days; just show the issue and say "see? You wanted it this way."

Also KSH is probably not the right tool; have a look at `awk`. This should work:

```
/^---+/,/^[ \t]*$/ { print; }
```

If you can't use awk, how about treating every line as a file name and ignore those which don't exist?

As long as no one creates a file named `FILE_NAME`, `4 rows selected.` or `SQL> spool off`, you should be find as long as you make sure you properly quote all strings.

Comment: That was a nice work around, but i guess i dont have access to change how the query works as i am part of the interface that comes into picture once the spool file is generated

Comment: +1 for yr last line :). hopefully they change the headings and echo